# Select (dropdown) with jcf plugin

Tags: html, css

I have a country and state dropdown. Our UI designer used jcf plugin which hides real select boxes and converts into a control which look and acts like a dropdown. It works well when I don't have to populate those select box dynamically from client side.

I have a country dropdown and based on selected list my state dropdown should populate. with jcf, I could see the real dropdown ( which is positioned left to -9999px) is populated but only first option shows up in a control that replaces that. Does anyone know how to display/populate the modified control.

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit: This seems to rebuild the select after I changed it.

```
$('#myselectbox')[0].jcf.buildDropdown(); // Rebuild based on options
$('#myselectbox')[0].jcf.refreshState(); // Updates to current selected
```

I have the exact same question and am in the process of getting the answer from the source.

This jcf.customForms "plugin" doesn't seem to have a lot of documentation.  You have probably used the same service (psdtohtml) or similar company to slice your design into HTML.  This seems to be some custom javascript related to that service.

A lot can be found by looking at the source or using `console.debug(jcf.customForms);` but I haven't found the solution yet.  Will update when I figure it out.

I've tried lots of stuff like

```
//jcf.customForms.setOptions(states[0]);
//jcf.customForms.refreshAll();
//jcf.customForms.refreshElement(states[0]);
//states.refreshState();
```

As for the previous answer, seem odd to have to `initTabs();` when you just want to reload a select.

Comment: It worked for me too! destroyAll() together with refreshAll() also worked for me. (jcf.customForms.destroyAll(); jcf.customForms.replaceAll();)

Comment: So glad. I had been dying to figure this framework out. I prefer to just select the element directly (document.getElementById('myselectbox').jcf), but knowing about this is a life saver.

Comment: Worked for me also thanks however for Daniel did destroyAll and replaceAll not make the elements vanish on the iPad?

Answer (score 6):

This is the code that worked for me. 
The code set a `select` fields value and then `refresh` and change the value using `jcf`, `select` fields will be selected with the option that have value 42

```
jQuery("#select-element").val("42");

jcf.getInstance(jQuery("#select-element")).refresh()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the following functions once again when you populating the state:

```
jcf.customForms.replaceAll();
initSlideShow();
initInputs();
initSameHeight();
initTabs();
fixSelect();initCounter();
initOpenClose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one line work for me. and its generic solution.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  jcf.customForms.replaceAll();
});
```

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to call the refresh method whenever the select box value changes

```
jcf.getInstance($("#select-box")).refresh()
```